# dockerfile - NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 10.16.0 (linux, x64)

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, instantclient, node-oracledb

I am behind a corporate firewall and I have a node.js application to deploy on Openshift container via a docker image. The application requires oracledb add-on binaries - Oracle InstantClient packages to be configured on the server.

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM devops-automation-docker<....>/rhel7-nodejs-10:latest
RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle
# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY . .

RUN mv instantclient_11_2 /opt/oracle
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

RUN sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf" && \
    ldconfig && \ 
    echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} && \
    npm ci 


EXPOSE 3002

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

The build is getting successful but when I deploy and run, it throws me following error:

> /usr/src/app/design-pattern-exemplars/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:68
>         throw new Error(nodbUtil.getErrorMessage('NJS-045', nodeInfo));
>         ^
>
> Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js
>   10.16.0 (linux, x64) Cannot load /usr/src/app/design-pattern-exemplars/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
>   /usr/src/app/design-pattern-exemplars/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node:
>   invalid ELF header Node-oracledb installation instructions:
>   https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html  You must have
>   64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with
>   ldconfig. If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then
>   install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/design-pattern-exemplars/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:68:13)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/design-pattern-exemplars/node_modules/oracledb/index.js:1:18)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. the first 2 commands were added after I saw some other post on SO which had some similar type of issue but it wasn't with docker and was run via sudo.

Please help! I went through other posts since last 10 days and I feel helpless now. Let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 1):

At a first guess, you are copying the node-oracledb install from a different host architecture.  Since node-oracledb has a binary component, this can cause problems.
But having said that, newer node-oracledb versions can be copied between the operating systems that pre-supplied binaries are available for.  What is your version of node-oracledb?  The latest is 4.0.  Do you have node-oracledb as a dependency in `package.json`?

My suggestions: start by doing an install in the Dockerfile following https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/dockerfiles-for-node-oracledb-are-easy-and-simple:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 oracle-nodejs-release-el7 && \
     yum-config-manager --disable ol7_developer_EPEL && \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite nodejs && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum

WORKDIR /myapp
ADD package.json /myapp/
ADD index.js /myapp/
RUN npm install

CMD exec node index.js
```

My `package.json` has `oracledb` as a dependency.  Note I don't even run ldconfig because the 19.3 RPM Instant Client already does that.

If it turns out that there isn't a binary for your docker container architecture, you will have to [compile from source code](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#github), again inside the Dockerfile.

Update: you may be interested in the new blog post [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Some comments:

- (i) why use such an old Instant Client - newer ones will connect to
  11.2 DB or later.  What's your DB version?
- (ii)  No need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH if you have already run ldconfig.
- (iii) when I am behind a fire wall, I add something like this to my Dockerfile: `ENV https_proxy=http://example.com:80` and/or `RUN npm
  config set proxy http://example.com:80`

Comment: In my package.json, the dependency version of oracledb is 3.1.1 and db version is 11g - 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Also, Since I am behind a corporate firewall, any installation would be a problem and the yum installations are not working perfectly. Currently, I do have instantclient zip of version 11.2. So If I upgrade to oracledb-4.0, will taht be compatible wioth my current instantclient version? Or I need a newer version of instantclient?

Comment: For yum I sometimes use `RUN echo proxy=http://proxy.example.com:80 >> /etc/yum.conf` in the Dockerfile. node-oracledb 4 works with Oracle client 11.2 or later.  Make sure your num install when you build the image is downloading node-oracledb.